# R is a quasi-semi-local ring, I is ideal of R. Prove Jac(R/I)=(JacR + I)/I

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

R is a quasi-semi-local ring (R has finitely many maximal ideals), I is ideal of R. Prove Jac(R/I)=(JacR + I)/I, in which Jac is Jacobson radical.

It's a problem in my teacher's book. I think we should divide maximal ideals of R into $M_1,...,M_k$ and $M_{k+1},...,M_n$, the first set consists of maximal ideals containing I. But I don't know what to do next

Comment: That's a valid start: from that you can conclude that $M_1,\ldots, M_k$ are the only maximal ideals involved in computing $J(R/I)$, and that they all contain $(J(R)+I)/I$, so you would have $J(R/I)\supseteq (J(R)+I)/I$. Not totally sure about the other containment: I might have expected this to hold for arbitrary rings, but maybe the semi-local condition is necessary!

Comment: Just to make sure, we have to prove $M_1\cap ...\cap M_k = M_1\cap...\cap M_n +I$, right?

Comment: The images of those ideals in the quotient ring $R/I$ yes. For example, $M_n$ has no presence in $R/I$ at all. You could say that you're actually checking $M_1\cap\ldots M_k\cap (M_{k+1}+I)\cap(M_{k+2}+I)\cap\ldots\cap (M_{n}+I)$

Comment: yeah! the other containment confuses me as well, any ideas?

Comment: I was going to see if the quasiregular-element definition of the radical was helpful.

Comment: Actually another thing to notice is that $M_j+I=R$ for every $j>k$. I'm not convinced that yields a complete proof, though yet. It seems more like corroborative evidence that the proposition is true. I think the reerse inclusion needs to be shown clearly.

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll try it that way